# PYTHON: How would a function be made for comparing recurring words within two lists?

Tags: python, list, function, count, call

For example:

```
q=["hi", "sky"]
p=["here","sky","sky","sky","sky"]
```

What would the function be defined to get:

```
count_words(["hi", "sky"], ["here","sky","sky","sky","sky"])
[0, 4]
# answer where hi appears 0 times and sky appears 4 times
```

I started the code off like this:

```
def count_words(q, p):
    count = 0
    for word in q:
        if q==p:
            (q.count("hi"))
            (q.count("sky"))
        return count
```

I keep getting one value of 0, which accounts for `q`, but I can't get a value for `p`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Avoid pasting screenshots if you can post your code in text form directly

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler answer (by simpler I mean one-liner and no use of additional libraries) -

```
q=["hi", "sky"] 
p=["here","sky","sky","sky","sky"]

def count_words(q,p):
    return [ p.count(i) for i in q ]

print(count_words(q,p))
```

**Output**

```
[0, 4]
```

**Explanation**

`[ p.count(i) for i in q ]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) which is like iterating through the `q` list on the fly and counting for the respective elements in `p`

**Timings (depends on the data)**

```
# My solution
1.78 µs ± 214 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# @Delirious Solution 1
7.55 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# @ Delirious Solution 2
3.86 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Although `count` is implemented in C, it seems inefficient to repeatedly iterate through `p` to count each word when it can be done in a single pass.

Comment: When your code takes `11min 10sec` to run versus `46.5ms` for the other solution, you've got a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
... 
... 
... def count_words(a, b):
...     cnt = Counter(b)
...     return [cnt[word] for word in a]
... 
>>> count_words(["hi", "sky"], ["here", "sky", "sky", "sky", "sky"])
[0, 4]
```

Or if you can't use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for some reason:

```
>>> def count_words(a, b):
...     cnt = {}
...     for word in b:
...         try:
...             cnt[word] += 1
...         except KeyError:
...             cnt[word] = 1
...     return [cnt.get(word, 0) for word in a]
... 
>>> count_words(["hi", "sky"], ["here", "sky", "sky", "sky", "sky"])
[0, 4]
```

EDIT:

It looks like there should be some timings to "clear things up" about which solution is more efficient. Since @chrisz forgot to post his actual test code, I had to do it myself.

Unfortunately, Vivek's code took `11min 10sec` to run while mine took only `46.5ms`.

```
In[18]: def vivek_count_words(q, p):
   ...:     return [p.count(i) for i in q]
   ...: 
In[19]: def lettuce_count_words(a, b):
   ...:     cnt = {}
   ...:     for word in b:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             cnt[word] += 1
   ...:         except KeyError:
   ...:             cnt[word] = 1
   ...:     return [cnt.get(word, 0) for word in a]
   ...: 
In[20]: # https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt
   ...: with open('moby_dick.txt', 'r') as f:
   ...:     moby_dick_words = []
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         moby_dick_words.extend(line.rstrip().split())
   ...: 
In[21]: len(moby_dick_words)
Out[21]: 215829
In[22]: from random import choice

In[23]: random_words = [choice(moby_dick_words) for _ in range(10)]
In[24]: %timeit vivek_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
31.3 ms ± 99.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In[25]: %timeit lettuce_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
20.7 ms ± 54.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In[26]: random_words = [choice(moby_dick_words) for _ in range(100)]
In[27]: %timeit vivek_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
211 ms ± 642 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In[28]: %timeit lettuce_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
20.6 ms ± 68.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In[29]: random_words = [choice(moby_dick_words) for _ in range(1000)]
In[30]: %timeit vivek_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
2.18 s ± 2.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In[31]: %timeit lettuce_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
22.2 ms ± 97.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In[32]: random_words = [choice(moby_dick_words) for _ in range(10000)]
In[33]: %timeit vivek_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
29.2 s ± 865 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In[34]: %timeit lettuce_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
25.7 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In[35]: random_words = [choice(moby_dick_words) for _ in range(100000)]
In[36]: %timeit vivek_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
11min 10s ± 7.51 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In[37]: %timeit lettuce_count_words(moby_dick_words, random_words)
46.5 ms ± 68.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```