# Count Occurrences using for, in, and return

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have been trying to write the code for this program for a while now, but I just cannot figure it out. I am very confused. I would appreciate the help:

---

Write a function that takes two strings. The second string should only be one character long. The function should return how many times the second string occurs in the first string.

You will need:

A function declaration, with parameters.
A for loop.
An if statement.
A return statement.

What I have so far:

```
string_one = "I love coding!" 
string_two = "I" 
if string_two in string_one: print "Hi"
```

Comment: what i have till now: string_one = "I love coding."
string_two = "I"


if string_two in string_one:
        print "Hi"                         after this, I tried using a for loop but then it would just print "Hi" a million times

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code. Not the comments

Comment: It would also be be useful to know what you're confused about. Hint: If you're printing within the loop, that's not counting characters in a string. Also, have you learned about functions?

Comment: You are not printing "Hi" for **every** time `string_two` is in `string_one`. See my answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the code you have provided, it indeed works if `string_two` is in `string_one`, meaning that your if-condition is correct. However, it will only run once, so if `string_two` occurs multiple times in `string_one`, it will ignore all other occurences and print `Hi` only once. As a result, you need to add your if-condition into a for-loop to catch all occurences of `string_two` in `string_one`.

```
string_one = "I love coding!" 
string_two = "o"  # changed to 'o' since it has more than 1 occurence in string_one
for letter in string_one:  # look at each letter in string_one, one after another
    if string_two in letter:  # also possible: if string_two == letter
        print "Hi"  # print Hi when the letter is found
```

All that's left to do now according to your task is to wrap this code into a function with two parameters (ideally one parameter called `sentence` and another one called `character` or similar) and return something. However, I will leave figuring this out to yourself, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's note that this problem could be solved using `str.count(thing_to_count)`. That's what you should use in general, but I see here you are probably asking for help on an assignement (generally discouraged on Stack Overflow, but I personally don't have an issue with it). Anyway, here's the code I made for this.

```
def count_in_string (sentence, thing_to_count):
    times = 0
    for word in sentence:
        for letter in word:
            if letter == thing_to_count: times += 1
    return times
```

So:

1. Declare `count_in_string` as a function with the arguments `sentence` and `thing_to_count`.
2. Set `times` to be the amount of times `thing_to_count_` appears in `sentence` (so far 0).
3. Loop through every word, and then letter in the sentence.
4. See if the letter is the `thing_to_count`, and if so add 1 to `times`.
5. Return `times` as the result.

Comment: `str.count` can be great if you are looking for very few things but if you are doing a lot of lookups, even though it is written in C, it is an inefficient way to count things compared to using something like `collections.Counter` where you count everything in a single pass and can then query that dict. I answered a question the other day where someone used `str.count` instead of counting everything in a single pass and during testing their solution took over `11 minutes` to run versus `46ms` for the single pass. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49103929/8079103